# Dynamic value Apex

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

Currently have this line of code.

```
<li><a href="{!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download, '00Pr0000ID00000')}" target="_blank" name="Application" id ="{!ApplicationObj.id}">Download</a></li>
```

Is there a way to pass this Application.Obj.id to the controller? So that logic can be done so the 00Pr0000ID00000 attachment Id is not static?

Comment: Please edit your post to explain what functions you are trying to do with the page and controller.  It doesn't make sense for the page to pass the ID to the controller unless you are expecting input or a URL parameter on the page, but you have not explained that.

Comment: @ebar You need to query the ID for the attachment in your controller. If you don't know how to get the ID from the page, that's an entirely different question. In this case, it would have been more useful to include all the relevant code, not just a single line of code by itself. Context is often important when programming.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add the object inside the formula like you did in the `id` attribute.

This would be your changed code

```
<li><a href="{!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download, ApplicationObj.id)}" target="_blank" name="Application" id ="{!ApplicationObj.id}">Download</a></li>
```

Comment: Well, the application object has attachments and I need the attachment id to be more clear. But I need to pass the applicationobj.id to the controller to grab one specific attachment to download.

Comment: Hey there, you're not being clear *at all* on your questions. I frankly have no idea of what you need.

Comment: How to click a link to download/view pdf of an attachment?